# Which non-state authorities can issue car license plates?

Tags: ukraine

In Uzhhorod, Ukraine, I saw cars with unusual car license plates, not assigned to Ukraine or other country, but probably to the OBSE organisation.

Which other organisations can issue their own license plates?

[image]

Comment: International organizations, military that organize and maintains their own car-parks and are not mainly locally based often have their own license plates.

Comment: Probably any organization created by treaty. These are from the [OSCE](https://www.osce.org/whatistheosce). The MU at the end apparently means they are assigned to the mission to Ukraine. I understand that these are treated similarly to diplomatic plates.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the fact that these plates exist is probably due to the immunity granted to the organization and its staff.  But that does not mean that the plates were issued by the organization itself.  Diplomatic plates are generally, in my experience at least, issued by the authorities of the host country.

Comment: @phoog Apparently OSCE does indeed issue its own plates. I was able to find numerous examples online.

Comment: Whether a non-state authority's license plates are valid will depend on the law (or tolerance!) of the state or country involved. Apparently, Ukraine accepts OSCE's plates.This doesn't mean Ukraine would necessarily accept other entities' plates, nor that OSCE plates would necessarily be acceptable in other countries.

Comment: I think this might be more common than you believe and I am not sure if this is on topic here. FWIW, German Wikipedia has pages with some examples for international and EU organisations issuing their own license plates: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kfz-Kennzeichen_internationaler_Organisationen  https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kfz-Kennzeichen_(Europ%C3%A4ische_Union)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a practical travel question.